# I can't read JSON in php

Tags: php, json

I have this small snippet of code in PHP to read a JSON sent by Ajax, and when I read it, the return is always empty.

```
<?php
    
$json='{"count":3,"value":[{"Code":"1","Name":"Carlos"},{"Code":"2","Name":"Charles" },{"Code":"3","Name":"Joseph"}]}';

$data = json_decode($json,true);

foreach($data as $row){
    $code=$row['Code'];    
    $name=$row['Name'];
}
```

Thank You.

Comment: Try `var_dump($data);` and see what you get, notice the nesting of the arrays.

Comment: If I use the json this way it works:
$json='[{"Code":"1","Name":"Carlos"},{"Code":"2","Name":"Charles" },{"Code":"3", "Name":"Joseph"}]'

The problem is that it is being sent like that by Ajax.

Comment: Required reading: [How to extract and access data from JSON with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-to-extract-and-access-data-from-json-with-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close. `$data['value']` has the list of items.

```
foreach ($data['value'] as $row) {
    print_r($row);
    $code = $row['Code'];
    $name = $row['Name'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try `foreach($data["value"] as $row)` instead of `foreach($data as $row)`